# facebook fql query to retrieve friends posted items

Tags: facebook, facebook-fql

Is there any fql statements allowed by facebook that helps to fetch contents of this page through an application interface: http://www.facebook.com/posted.php I know the links table returns the posted item for a logged in user (http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/links). I need the same but for the logged-in user's friends.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

you can use Fql query or Graph API to get your friends data.
Sometimes  you will not get all information from the graph like birthdate of your friends but yes you can use fql queries to solve your probs.

here is an exmple for you.

create first facbook object and the use it.

$query = "SELECT uid, first_name, last_name, birthday_date, sex, pic_square, current_location, hometown_location FROM user WHERE uid IN (SELECT uid2 FROM friend WHERE uid1 = me()) AND birthday_date != 0 ORDER BY birthday_date";

Regards,
Archit.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this through an FQL query - though you may need to use multiple queries if you require more information about the friend who posted the link:

```
select title, owner from link where owner in (select uid2 from friend where uid1 = me() limit 100)
```

You may want to limit the number of friends (or even the links themselves) as this can be a costly query